# Can an array of 8 longs fit in a 64 byte cache line?

Tags: c#, caching

So on Intel's I7 Processor memory is written and read at 64 bytes.
So if I wanted to fill a cache line up, I could use 16 longs (4 bytes each).

If a make an array of 16 longs, would that fit the entire cache line, or is there some overhead for the array?

My concern is that if an array has any overhead at all, and I use 16 longs, the total size in bytes will spill over 64.

So is it more like `new long[63]`, or `new long[62]` etc?

Comment: why do you think that you can write directly to the cache?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName I don't. But I know the cpu has three layers of cache, and the third layer reads 64 bytes from main memory when getting a value.

Comment: A .NET array certainly has  an overhead. Something like 20 bytes or so. But a 1 MB array will still profit from the cache, 64 bytes at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, the `long` data type, which is an alias for `System.Int64`, is 8 bytes, not 4. The `int` type, aka `System.Int32`, is 4 bytes. So 64 bytes of `long` values is eight elements, not sixteen.

The storage of a managed array is in fact contiguous, so in theory yes, a `long[8]` would fit in a 64-byte cache line exactly. But note that it would do so only if properly aligned on an address that's a multiple of 64. Since you don't have control over allocation location, that's going to be difficult to do.

So even without overhead in the array, you can't guarantee that a single 8-element array of `long`s would actually fit exactly in a 64-byte cache line.

Of course, an array longer than that will have sub-ranges that are aligned and so can be cached entirely. But then that's true for pretty much any data type you might have. Frankly, the thing to worry about isn't the size of your data or the length of your array, but the pattern of access. See "data locality" for advice on how to access your data in ways that help ensure efficient use of the cache.